# Site not found attempting to access my-app.firebaseapp.com

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I've deployed a PWA to firebase hosting and there are 2 URLS.

This one works:
app-name-axdax.web.app

This one generates the following error on an app when used:
app-name-axdax.firebaseapp.com
[image]

Not sure why the firebaseapp.com link isn't working on an app, I followed the tutorial precisely.  I need that feature so users can add the app to their homescreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase DNS does take some time to propagate on newly created projects and can take up to 24 hours to finalize.

- If you believe it has been long enough, You can attempt a cache
  refresh (Ctrl+F5) or try another browser.
- If it has been 48 hours and no change, You should contact Firebase
  support who can debug the settings internally.